# Django formset security

Tags: django, django-forms, formsets

I've noticed something in Django formsets:

Each formset.form has a hidden field with the id of the model being edited. All one would need to do is change this id and submit, and the default formset `clean()` or `save()` methods don't bat an eye.

I would think that it wouldn't be too complicated to keep track of which objects were in the original formset queryset, and compare them on save. I wonder why Django doesn't do this already?

As for me, I'm checking permissions on formset save like:

```
if formset.is_valid():
    for fs in formset:
        report = fs.save(commit=False)
        if can_edit(request.user, report):
            report.save()
```

Anyone else notice this issue? I'd be curious to see how you've addressed it.

Comment: As far as I remember, it's not possible to edit an object with pk `y` (which isn't in the queryset) by changing the hidden id from `x` to `y`. If you have found otherwise, I think that's a security issue and it would be better to report it privately rather than posting on Stack Overflow. I don't think there's a specific reason for the current lack of error message -  I think a patch would be welcomed.

Comment: It is possible (provided the `request.user` has edit permission on the model). I've just tried it.

Comment: Regular model formsets do not check `request.user` at all. Are you talking about the Django admin?

Comment: No, I'm talking about a regular formset. I assumed Django was checking. In that case, it's even worse.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the necessary permissions to edit that other object, then why should Django prevent you from doing so? HTTP requests are stateless, so when a POST comes in, Django will check if you are allowed to perform the request.

So, let's say you are authenticated and have permission to change `Comment` objects. Your form has a comment with `id=1`. You change the hidden field to `id=2` and submit the form. Django will check your permissions and see that you are allowed to change any `Comment` instance and apply the POSTed change.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. But since Django doesn't ship with object-level permissions, it's a bit of a gotcha. E.g., I can make sure that the objects on the formset belong to the `request.user` pretty easily, but that doesn't give any protection.

Comment: There are so many convenient tools like `is_valid()`, `csrf_token` and the `permission_required` decorator, it seems like a little method to see if the formset has been monkeyed with would be a good idea.

Comment: Its not so much Django as it is HTTP that doesn't work that way. You could achieve what you want by putting all the `id`s into a string, then hashing it, and sending that hash along to the client, and when the client submits the form, you take the submitted `id`s again, hash them, and compare the two hashes. Another way would be, you put the list of `id`s into the user's session object and compare when you receive the form. But again, that's not how it should be done.

Comment: Or perhaps I could just save queryset info before I get to the `if request.method == 'POST'` condition. Then extract the ids and use them for comparison.